# MySql combining two columns from 2 tables using UNION

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to take 2 tables from a MySql database and output  2 specific column's from each table and combine the values of the columns into a regular table of 4 columns using the UNION statement to weed through the duplicates.

I have 2 tables one is called (tblproducts) and the other (tblpricing)
There are 2 columns in each of the tables i want to display their values into a regular table.

(tbleproducts)
->name         <-this is a column of product names
->description  <- this is a column of descriptions of each product

(tblpricing)
->monlthy      <--this is the monthly price
->annually     <--this is the yearly price

[You can see the tables displaying here](http://shawktech.com/demo/about/)

MY only problem is this code below, the Yearly and monthly does not display, just the name and description. 
I have  renamed the JOINS to opposite of each other and they will display the values of YEARLY and MONTHLY but in the wrong columns, so i know it is not the echo table code that is the problem. Its the order of wi

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT tblproducts.description, tblproducts.name 
FROM `tblpricing` RIGHT JOIN `tblproducts` on annually = tblproducts.id 
UNION SELECT tblpricing.monthly, tblpricing.annually
FROM `tblproducts` LEFT JOIN `tblpricing` on monthly = tblpricing.id; "))



echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

(tbleproducts)
    name
    description

(tblpricing)
    monthly
    yearly
below are some links to pictures to help you.
[Picture of both databases and oy complete code](http://shawktech.com/images/allpics.png)

Comment: I suggest rewording the question such that it's clear. We don't know what youre trying to accomplish here. Try to provide an example.

Comment: Consider to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21322318/edit) your question and provide sample data for your tables and the desired output to clarify your question.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: How much more sample data do you need I sent pictures, i explained the best i could, you guys keep asking for more? what more can i provide?

Comment: You have posted inscrutably small pictures.  Put the data and desired results in the question.

Comment: the images should expand? What data? The tables have thousands of columns and 100's thousands of tables.

Comment: on the page [http://shawktech.com/demo/about/] also located above i re-added the images all on the same page. Please have a look.